# ArcPy select by location to copy attribute values from one shapefile to another

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have two shapefiles, lines and points.  I want to copy over the lines number to the points that are near each line.

I can use select by location in ArcMap and label manually for a small scale, but need to automate on a larger scale.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) tool, and choose `WITHIN A DISTANCE` for your match option. Input a distance that will work with your data for the search distance.